# After Cloning Repo - Source Does Not Appear In Eclipse Java View

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, github

I'm trying to import the source code for a github project into eclipse and I was able to pull the repo using https://github.com/madeye/proxydroid.git - it now appears in my Git Repository View however I do not see the source code when I switch to Java view.

Any ideas on what I may have done wrong? I've tried pulling and fetching from upstream and I still have nothing in my java view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository you cloned will appear in your git folder, which I believe is in your "My Documents" folder by default. Your default eclipse workspace is not the same as this.

So you fix this two or three different ways. Change your git folder to clone your repo's to your eclipse workspace, import the source files into eclipse and work on it outside of your eclipse workspace, or change your eclipse workspace to the git folder.

Hope that helps! It's pretty easy to fix once you know whats going on.